# Process fluentd logs with a script before outputting them to stdout

Tags: ruby, docker, fluentd

I have a docker container running fluentd that collects logs from several other containers. I want to process the incoming logs using a script, so I searched their documentation and found [@type exec_filter](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/exec_filter) which to me sounded like just what I was searching for. So I am trying to set up the most basic example, as shown in their documentation:

**fluent.conf**

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24226
  bind 0.0.0.0
  tag logs
</source>

<match *>
  @type exec_filter
  command ruby /rtest.rb
  tag logs
  <format>
    @type json
  </format>
  <parse>
    @type msgpack
  </parse>
  <buffer>
    flush_interval 10s
  </buffer>
</match>
```

**rtest.rb**

```
require 'json'
require 'msgpack'

begin
  while line = STDIN.gets # continue to read a event from stdin
    line.chomp!

    # Input format depends on exec_filter's in_format setting
    json = JSON.parse(line)

    # main processing. You can do anything, mutate record, access to database and etc.
    json['new_field'] = "Hey from exec_filter script!"

    # Write data to stdout. Output format depends on exec_filter's out_format setting
    STDOUT.print MessagePack.pack(json)

    # Call flush to avoid buffering events
    STDOUT.flush
  end
rescue Interrupt # Ignore Interrupt exception because it happens during exec_filter shutdown
end
```

I copy the rtest.rb into my docker containers root directory ("/"). Builds and run the container and use docker logs fluentd-container --follow and make sure there should be something sent to it. But nothing prints...

Have I misunderstood something? How can I process incoming data and then print it to stdout so I can follow the processed data using docker logs fluentd-container --follow?

**EDIT:**
I have also tried this fluent.conf file since I figured I had to print something to stdout:

**fluent.conf**

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24226
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<match *>
  @type stdout
  format json
  tag logs
</match>

<match *>
  @type exec_filter
  command ruby /rtest.rb
  tag logs
  <format>
    @type json
  </format>
  <parse>
    @type msgpack
  </parse>
  <buffer>
    flush_interval 10s
  </buffer>
</match>
```